# find that a specific item in a List with different Items is not null

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `List<GroceryItems>`
where GroceryItems has the following items :`typeOfBread`,`water`,`milk`

the fields are nullable, so I get them also if are null, with a null value of course.

I need to *count* how many `val typeOfBread :String?` are effectively present, not null in my List (Actually I would be content also if I know is more than one)

Please how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to get the number of non-null types of bread do this:

```
val numberOfNonNullBreadTypes = groceryList.count { it.typeOfBread != null }
```

If you would like to get a new list containing only the non-null ones you could do this:

```
val filteredList = groceryList.filter { it.typeOfBread != null }
```

Comment: I come up with the solution, is indeed what you did, but should be added`.count()` so that I get the int, if you add count to the edit, I am going to accept the response:)

Comment: @Johnsmith the first piece of code i gave returns just the int, the second piece of code gets a filtered list. You could call `.count()` on the list, though if you only need the int you should use the first piece of code instead.

Comment: @Johnsmith i updated answer slightly to make it more clear